# Targeting .htaccess file with file_put_contents

Tags: htaccess

I have a htaccess file and the path to access it is:

wordpress/.htaccess

When I use:

```
file_put_contents('wordpress/.htaccess', implode('', $data));
```

I get the error "Failed to open stream"...

How do you target a htaccess file with file_put_contents? From what I can tell the path is correct

Comment: What have you tried? **1.** How about permissions of that file? **2.** Did you tried other paths? Just in case, maybe you're wrong.. Have you tried just `/.htaccess` or added directory that contains `/wordpress/.htaccess`? **3.** Did you try to `echo implode('', $data);`? Is everything okay with that?

Comment: yea maybe its a permissions issue. Ill check. Thanks for the reminder.